# How to get listbox column text with xul

Tags: xul

I am new with xul,

I want to know how to get listbox column text with xul,

I search about listbox method and property, but I can't find about that

please help!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the reference page [listbox - XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/listbox)

If you want to get the  selected item, there is a property of the listbox called  selectedItem that will return it.

Your listitem can be composed with multiple  elements.

```
<listbox id="list">
    <listitem class="listitem">
        <listcell class="column1" value="value1" width="100"/>
        <listcell class="column2" value="value2" width="100"/>
    </listitem>
</listbox>
```

If you give this  elements a class, you can access them doing the following:

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var listItem = list.selectedItem;
var column1Value = listItem.getElementsByClassName("column1")[0].getAttribute("value");
var column1Value = listItem.getElementsByClassName("column2")[0].getAttribute("value");
```